# Don't close Top Bar Settings Panel when clicked

Tags: bluetooth, settings, system-tray, top-bar

I find it extremely annoying when I for example turn on wifi or bluetooth from the top right system tray (or top bar, no clue what it's called) and it automatically closes. Is there any way to keep it open until I click out of it?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu?

Comment: I'm on version 20.10

Answer (score 0):

I experience the same annoyance. It is about the Quick Settings window to be more specific. When clicking outside that window, it should close.